# Python use of any(), which one matches?

Tags: python, list, match, any

I'm writing a script to sort logfiles into more convenient data and to do so I use the any() function. I now know if part of a string matches any of the items in my list. Here's the function:

```
    def logfiles(self):

    look_for = ['network', 'skip', 'remove', 'jitter', 'loss', 'diff']
    analyze = self.open_logs('logfile-1.log')
    result = []

    for i in analyze:
        i = i.strip()

        if any(search in i for search in look_for):
            result.append(i)

    return result
```

This will tell me if part of the string i matches any of the items in my list look_for. However, is there a way to also detect which item matches? I haven't been able to find a built-in way for any() to do so and don't think there is one so how would one go about solving this? This particular snippet is a lot faster than a previous method I used (a simple loop basically) so I'd prefer to continue using this..

Thanks!

Comment: Half-joking answer: wait and see if [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) get integrated into a future version of the language. Capturing a witness from an any() expression is explicitly one of the feature's motivations :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `any`, you're semantically discarding the return value. You don't care which one, you just care that if `any` of them is true.

I suggest using a explicit for, instead. It is clearer, and removes the complexity of a obscure next() with exception handling. Performance is the same:

```
for search in look_for:
    if search in i:
        break
else:
    print('Not found...')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next((search for search in look_for if (search in i)), None)` to get the first matching element.  It's still short-circuiting so it will stop searching after it finds a match.  If no match is found, the second argument will be returned.

Comment: But this raises `StopIteration` if nothing is found.

Comment: This would require handling `StopIteration` for the case where nothing is found. (Which may be the best answer, but you should explain it here.)

Comment: Or passing an appropriate second argument to `next()`.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.  I didn't know about that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sure, but in this case that’s not going to end up any less verbose, and it means you have to pick a value that you know can never show up (or create one with `_sentinel=object()`).